# Said, "Assembly successfully added to the cache" but it's not in the cache

Tags: .net, com, assemblies, gac, .net-assembly

The feedback I got:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>gacutil.
exe /i "C:\Users\wherever\ClassLibrary1.dll"
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>
```

But it's not in a search of the contents of

```
gacutil.exe /l | clip
```

And it's not in /Windows/assemblies

I'm using .net 4.

Comment: Thanks.  Is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe /l designed to pick up the presence of an assembly in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL ?

Comment: The copy of gacutil.exe that is under netfx 4.0 tools should be pulling in from both assembly locations. For instance on a system with .net 1.1, 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0 installed if you run micrsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\bin\gacutil.exe /lr you will see two assemblies returned if you run the gacutil.exe from .netfx 4.0 tools you will see 3 assemblies listed.

Answer (score 8):

.Net 4.0 assemblies are in a different location. They exist at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly

Comment: how to add them in windows assembly folder?